# How to refresh post request to api whenever the element to post is changed in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, frontend, angular11

I am trying to code a car rent web site front end. The api has an api/filter controller and I need to post the filter object:

```
export interface Filter {
    brandNames:string[],
    colorNames:string[],
    priceMin:number,
    priceMax:number,
    dateStart:Date,
    dateEnd:Date
}
```

I keep this "filter" object in a searchService:

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class SearchService {
  searchText: string = ""

  emptyDate:Date = new Date(0,0,0)

  readonly emptyFilter: Filter = {
    brandNames: [],
    colorNames: [],
    priceMin: 0,
    priceMax: 0,
    dateEnd: this.emptyDate,
    dateStart: this.emptyDate
  }
  filter: Filter = this.emptyFilter
}
```

I have a few sidebar sections which manipulate each property of the filter, and there are two child components under the sidebar component one for brandNames and one for colorNames. for example one of them is:

```
<app-brand></app-brand>
<app-color></app-color>  
  
<div class="shadow pt-2">
      <form class="form-control">
        <label for="startDate" class="form-label">Start Date: </label>
        <input type="date" [value]="startDatePlaceHolder" min="{{minDate}}" class="form-date" id="startDate" 
            name="startDate" [(ngModel)]="selectedStartDate">
      <hr>
      <label for="dueDate" class="form-label">Due Date: </label>
      <input type="date" [value]="dueDatePlaceHolder" class="form-date" id="dueDate" name="dueDate" [(ngModel)]="selectedDueDate">
      
        <button type="button" (click)="setDateFilter()" class="btn btn-dark">Filter</button>
      </form>
    </div>
    
    <div class="shadow pt-2 d-grid gap-2">
      <button type="button" (click)="clearAllFilters()" class="btn btn-dark">Clear All Filters</button>
    </div>
```

Now the question is, I want to post this filter to api and dynamically update the car list in response on any change which should be invoked by clicking on a brandName (= adds the clicked brandName to brandNames array of filter) or clicking on "Filter" button after picking a price range.

This is the carDto service:

```
constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) { }
  getCarDtoListByFilter(filter: Filter): Observable<any> {

    let path = this.apiUrl + "/filter"
    return this.httpClient.post(path, filter, this.options)
  }
```

This is the component which the carDtos are listed:

```
  constructor(private carDtoService: CarDtoService,
    private carImageService: CarImageService,
    private searchService: SearchService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getCarDetailsListByFilter()
  }

  getCarDetailsListByFilter() {
    this.carDtoService.getCarDtoListByFilter(this.searchService.filter).subscribe(result => {
      this.carDtoList = result.data
    })
  }
```

[folder structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NihfP.png)
[appearance of sidebar and carDtoList](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qx4nO.png)

Answer (score 0):

you have to rennounce at ngModel and use the reactive forms.

component controller:

```
selectedStartDate: FormControl = new FormControl('');

ngOnInit(): void {
  this.selectedStartDate.valueChanges
      .pipe(
         startsWith(''),
         distinctUntilChanged()
      ).subscribe(value => {
           // send filter value
           this.getCarDetailsListByFilter();
      });
}
```

template

```
 <input type="date" [value]="startDatePlaceHolder" min="{{minDate}}" class="form-date" id="startDate" 
            name="startDate" [formControl]="selectedStartDate">
```